# Reading from file in Release version of c# app

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have a problem with my app in C#.

My program is supposed to read from the Resources file named TextFile1.txt paths to some files and parse them as arguments to another executable script.

In debug version program works well and after changes in TextFile1 program takes updated arguments but in Release version app does not update this changes.

Here is C# function that reads from file

```cs
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedItem = (string)listBox1.SelectedItem;
    if (selectedItem != null)
    {
        string[] parts = selectedItem.Split('\\');
        string NX_exe = "\\App.exe";
        string path = string.Join("\\", parts, 0, parts.Length - 1);
        string arguments = string.Join(" ", destinationPath, path + NX_exe);

        byte[] fileBytes = Properties.Resources.SignDotNet_Script;

        string exeFilePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "App_Script.exe");
        File.WriteAllBytes(exeFilePath, fileBytes);

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

        startInfo.FileName = exeFilePath;

        if (destinationPath == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Destination Path", "SignDotNetApp",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            return;
        }

        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            startInfo.Arguments = destinationPath + " " + '"' + path + NX_exe + '"' + " y";
        }
        else
        {
            startInfo.Arguments = destinationPath + " " + '"' + path + NX_exe + '"';
        }

        Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);

        process.WaitForExit();

        MessageBox.Show("Signing Completed", "SignDotNetApp",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        File.Delete(exeFilePath);
    }
}
```

and here is an example of TextFile1

```
ProgramName1,   C:\Program Files\ExecutablePath_1\App.exe
ProgramName2,   C:\Program Files\ExecutablePath_2\App.exe
ProgramName3,   C:\Program Files\ExecutablePath_3\App.exe
```

I do not know how to change that and I would appreciate some advice about this issue

Comment: instead of `string.Join('\\', parts, ...)` you should look at `Path.Combine(parts, ...)`. That will set you up to eventually run on a system that might instead use the forward slash (`/`) as the separator character, as well as ensure you don't run into trouble with invalid characters in the path.

Comment: The `BaseDirectory` directory will be projectDirectory/bin/Debug in Debug mode and projectDirectory/bin/Release in Release mode. [Debug your code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger) and inspect the values stored in the relevant variables to find the problem.

Comment: Starting a food fight with every anti-malware product in existence is not wise, the mashed potatoes will finish you off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey I found the answer to that question, it's not the most brilliant but it works for me.

```
string pathToMyFile = "Resources\\Paths.txt";

            string pathFile = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), pathToMyFile);


            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pathFile))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                     some code
                }
            }
```

Previously I was using

```
string resourceName = "SignDotNetApp.Resources.TextFile1.txt";
            
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(asm.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)))
            {
                some code
            }
```

and my program, by this instruction, was storing Paths.txt at first build

Now at each run, it's reloading Paths.txt and applying changes